# VMware workstation 16 is not working in hyper-v enabled host windows 10 2004

Tags: windows-10, vmware, hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux, virtualization-based-security

I have installed VMware workstation 16 on Hyper-V enabled host windows.

[image]
[image]

The windows version is Win 10 2004 pro and hyper-v, wsl, sandbox are enabled to run docker.
[image]
[image]

Even though virtualization-based service is running, I could not power on VM and it's sending an error message of "VMware Workstation and Device/Credential Guard are not compatible"

[image]
[image]

I have also enabled VBS support in guest VM, but still, it's not working.

[image]

Comment: "Device/Credential Guard are not compatible"   <-- That error has come up for me when try to run VMware Workstation and Sandbox at the same time. They are not compatible. Disable Sandbox and see if Workstation works withn Hyper-V enabled host.

Comment: Suspect this is an incompatibility with 20H2, if that’s the case, VMWare will release an update.  [This](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146361) article describes two registry keys, what are those values, provide those values as an edit to your question

Comment: Please provide the mksSandbox.log and vmware.log on something like pastebin

Comment: I was going to submit an answer that indicates you should disable Device/Credential Guard but I was able to confirm that Windows 10 2004 and VMWare Workstation 16 are compatible.  This means your issue is a compatibility issue with Windows 10 20H2

Comment: I have tested after disabling sandbox, but still it didn't work

Comment: According to vmware site doc, workstation must detect hyper-v and operate in host vbs-mode, but it seems it's not detecting and operating in traditional mode.

As I think, there is a problem in installed vbs, but not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved issue by disabling Credential Guard.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/credential-guard-manage#disable-windows-defender-credential-guard

Now both hyper-v and vmware can operate, though I can't use VT-x in guest vm.

It seems like VBS is different from credential guard.